# Datastax Cassandra Remove and cleanup one column family

Tags: cassandra, datastax

After some IT cleanup, we are noticing that we should probably do a full cleanup / restore for one column family.  We believe that Cassandra has duplicate data that it is not cleaning up.  Is it possible to clear out and just have Cassandra rebuild a single column family from scratch or a snapshot?

During an upgrade some of the nodes decided to rejoin the cluster, rather than just restarting.  During that process `nodetool netstats` showed that nodes where transferring new data file into the original nodes.  The cluster is stable, but the disk usage grew substantially.  I am thinking that we will migrate to a new ring, but in the mean time I would like to see if I can reduce some disk usage.  The ring is stable, and repairs are looking fine.

If we are able to cleanup one cf it would relieve disk space usage a ton.

`nodetool cleanup` is not reducing the size of the sstables.

If we have a new node join the cluster it is using approximately 50% of the disk space as the other nodes.

We could do the dance of `nodetool decommision` && `nodetool join`, but that is not going to be fun :)

We have validated that the data in the ring is consistent, and repairs show that the data is consistent across the ring.

Comment: Short answer: 'yes'. What symptoms are you seeing that lead you to a 'duplicate data' diagnosis?

Comment: See edits - update for your question

Comment: you can also run `nodetool cleanup` command to clean up all the data that is not owned by the particular node anymore. This behavior is usually observed when you add more capacity to your cluster.

Comment: @MUFC Added more information. `nodetool cleanup` is not cleaning house.

Comment: We have successfully used `nodetool scrub` followed by a `nodetool clearsnapshot`. This does rebuild the sstable from scratch. It also leaves a snapshot in case of failure (that's why the `clearsnapshot` is there afterwards), so it's pretty safe. Worked very well in our (fairly specific) case!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new node and successfully running repair means the data for the partition range(s) that has(have) been assigned to that node has been streamed to the new node.

If, after this has happened, you run nodetool cleanup, any data from the other nodes that is no longer needed is cleaned up.

If you still see that some of your nodes have more data than others, this may be because you have some wider rows in some of your partitions, or because your nodes are unbalanced. There should not be any data duplication scenario (if you can prove this then it would be jira worthy).

You can run rebalance in OpsCenter or manually re-assign your tokens if you are looking to spread out the data more evenly across your nodes (or design your data model to avoid the aforementioned wide rows).

Answer (score 0):

Use nodetool compact to clean up all the tombstones and compacts all the updated records into single record.

{`nodetool compact`}